# Set-Cookie not working on Opera/Firefox but it does on Postman. (express)

Tags: node.js, angular, express, cookies, setcookie

I've been reading for a whole day about people who had this same problem and i've tried everything I could, but cant seem to make it work.

I think it's related to browser security policy, my **server and client are running both on different localhost ports** and browser threats them as different domains.

However, as I said, the cookie its set if I make the post request from Postman.

**Cookieparser and cors are enabled and tried multiple configurations for them, none worked.**

Also tried different settings for domain and path with same result.

I also thought that it could be related to my browser addons or something like that, but I tried with incognito, other browsers and got the same results...

**The client app its on Angular**, but I doubt that has anything to do with the problem from what I've read.

```
res.cookie("SESSIONID", jwtBearerToken, { domain: 'localhost', secure: false, httpOnly: false, path: '/', maxAge: 9000000 }).send();
```

What I get on browser:

[REQUEST AND RESPONSE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bT04M.png)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it myself.

Had to specify the origin, seens like wildcard '*' wasnt valid with credentials

```
app.use(cors({
    origin: 'http://localhost:4200',
    credentials: true
}));
```

Then on my angular http request I had to add `withCredentials: true` (which I already tried, but using the wildcard on the origin).

Hope this is useful for anyone!